# Black colors not as deep as they used be

Tags: macos, display, high-sierra, color

It appears that my display settings have changed all of a sudden. Black colors are not as dark as they used to be, blacks look kind of grey now, and whole display looks yellowish. I haven't changed any settings.

My settings:

Display profile: COLOR LCD
Night shift - color temperature: in the middle

I'm using macbook pro 13 ntb with high sierra.

Comment: Does the problem persist when night shift is disabled?

Comment: It did. I just restarted the computer and everything seems back to normal...